# Custom Window Style in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nspanel

**OK, this is what I'm trying to do :**

- I have a custom `NSPanel` subclass
- I want the `NSPanel` to be borderless (NO title - I'm drawing a titlebar myself) AND resizeable

**The thing is that :**

- once I set the `styleMask` to `NSResizableWindowMask`, the default title bar appears as well.
- once I set the `styleMask` to `NSBorderlessWindowMask`, the default title bar disappears (that's good), but the window loses its resizing ability.

**This is my Code :**

```
- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSUInteger)windowStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)deferCreation
{
    if ((self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask backing:bufferingType defer:deferCreation])) {
        [self setOpaque:NO];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
        [self setMovableByWindowBackground:YES];
        [self setLevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel];
        //[self setStyleMask:[self styleMask]&~NSTitledWindowMask];
    }
    return self;
}
```

As you may see from the commented-out code, I've tried using any possible combination of bit operations with the mask so that I combine what I need.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Just do them at a time like this

```
styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask
```